# CakePHP Routing, reverse redirection

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Let's say i have a controller `Articles` and an action `Search`.

I have set the router configuration in *routes.php* like this:

```
Router::connect(
                 '/search/:search_term/*', 
                 array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'search')
);
```

This way i can see the article titles containing '*cakephp*' in search results when i navigate to `http://localhost/search/cakephp`

But if i navigate to `http://localhost/articles/search/cakephp` i see the same results.

What i want is to be automatically redirected to

```
http://localhost/search/cakephp
```

when i navigate to

```
http://localhost/articles/search/cakephp
```

based on the configuration in *routes.php*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create .htaccess redirect for that you can't do it with routes:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/search/(.+)$ /search/$1 [L,NC]
```

OK I found something but not quite sure it will work:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/articles/search/*',
    '/search/',
    array('persist' => true)
);
```

Comment: A few minutes trying `Router::redirect` and it seems we are on to something. However do you have any idea how to redirect the parameters too? Like; redirect _/articles/search/cakephp_ to _/search/cakephp_.

Comment: according the documentation this: `'persist' => true` should do the transfer of any parameters that are matched with the `*` in first line

Comment: Thanks, you solution works. _Router::redirect('/articles/search/*', array('controller' => 'search', array('persist' => true)));_ sohuld work too. Acting like search is a controller and passing the params after that.